# Spark Partition: Do I need to use the partition column in the query in order to take advantage of the performance partition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I have a table in Spark partition by a column year_month (eg. 2020-01, 2020-02), but all the queries are done using a different column from with the year_month is derived date (e.g. 2020-01-30, 2020-02-28).

There is only one record per month and the date column is the one used in all of the queries, the year_month is not used anywhere .

The main question is. In this scenario will spark performance as a partition or will it read all the table in each query because date is not the partition column.

Comment: I believe you would want to repartition your table by the new derived column. however, i am not certain this is the case – running some benchmarks using sample data partitioned by a particular field might help answer your question (and i'll give this a try if i have time later)

Comment: Pls show code for all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add the partitionBy column as a column in your query filter, for them to be effective. Spark has no way of knowing that the date and the partition column are strictly correlated.

What you can do it is to add a filter condition that is derived from the date for example, but in any case, you have to specify the `year_month` column.

You can expolore the use of this thanks to the `myQuery.explainPlan` API (here the reference for the SQL API, but you have the same for other languages).

Here you will see the number of partitions involved (should be one if you use the correct filter), the number of parquet files involved, and other interesting information about your query and his execution.

Explain  SQL:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-explain.html

Explain Scala: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#explain(extended:Boolean):Unit